# How to specify bit/key size with gpg -c?

Tags: encryption, rsa, passwords, pgp

I'm trying to specify the RSA key size when using `-c` with gpg or gpg2. Example:

```
> gpg -c --armor --passphrase <password> --keysize 4096 file.txt
```

Is this possible? I couldn't find the command line flag in the gpg manpage. How many bits long is default when using `-c`?

Answer (score 1):

`-c`/`--symmetric` applies symmetric cryptography, ie. does not make use of public/private key algorithms like RSA. Ciphers for symmetric cryptography know a block key size, but this directly depends on the algorithm used and cannot be directly compared with RSA key sizes. From `man gpg`:

> Encrypt with a symmetric cipher using a passphrase. The default symmetric cipher used is AES-128, but may be chosen with the `--cipher-algo` option. This command may be combined  with  `--sign`  (for  a  signed  and symmetrically encrypted message), `--encrypt` (for a message that may be decrypted via a secret key or a passphrase), or `--sign` and
>                 `--encrypt` together (for a signed message that may be decrypted via a secret key or a passphrase).

You can change the used cipher algorithm using the `--cipher-algo` option:

> Use  name  as  cipher algorithm. Running the program with the command `--version` yields a list of supported algorithms. If this is not used the cipher algorithm is selected
>                 from the preferences stored with the key. In general, you do not want to use this option as it allows you to violate the OpenPGP  standard.   `--personal-cipher-preferences`
>                 is the safe way to accomplish the same thing.

GnuPG 2.1 allows the following symmetric ciphers:

```
$ gpg --version
[...]
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
[...]
```